# Website/app with list of the best low-cost flights deals within EU by city/airport?

Tags: air-travel, budget, online-resources, airports, eu

I am looking for a website/application that will allow me to monitor some airport or airports in some area and send me the deals when something is interesting (much cheaper than average) to my mail.

Example:
I am located in Rome and I don't know where I want to go, but I want the flight to be at least 50% cheaper than an average price of that flight. And if some flight suddenly became that cheap e.g. to Madrid or Budapest or London, I get an email or some other message or something like that.

Or if no email/messaging is available, then a website where I select some airport and it shows me some good deals for low-coast flights from that airport in the next couple of days or weeks, that would be great too.

Any idea if something like that exists?

Comment: "50% cheaper than average" is a poor definition. Flight prices fluctuate wildly between week days, seasons, carriers, special events and general supply and demand, which makes "average hard" to define. Below XXX amount is a better criteria. For example, lowest fares from Rome to Boston in August vary between 500-1000 Euro depending on date

Answer (score 2):

Sort of a match for what you're looking for: http://adioso.com.

Comment: Interesting approach on that site. Just don't expect up to date prices. As can be seen on sites such as [Skyscanner](http://skyscanner.com) already checking the prices for one connection can take up to half a minute or so. The search engine needs to query a lot of APIs and scrape a lot of web sites. And Skyscanner is probably one of the best engines out there… Also, airlines and travel agencies may punish excessive amounts of API/web requests, unless these requests correlate to a high number of bookings.

Comment: Well, the question basically asks for a website ;-) A few words on the functionality would be nice to know what to expect before clicking but even with a thoughtful description, if the website goes dead, the answer would be no good.

Comment: Where is that site quoting flight prices from?  I don't see a F.A.Q section and the video on what this site  is not working on my Android.  I can't tell what features it has....

Answer (score 2):

More of an answer to your secondary request, but [FlightChecker](http://flightchecker.moneysavingexpert.com/) by MoneySavingExpert is my go-to tool for 'flights under £X' using low-cost carriers to European destinations (either a specific place, anywhere in a given country or simply anywhere in Europe), within a range of dates or on specific dates.